# Где нужно закрывать cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor, cursoradaper

Где будет правильней всего закрывать cursor? Есть такой метод, который вызывается при создании новой записи в БД, обновлении существующей записи, удалении записи, а также в методе onCreate при запуске приложения:

```
private void fillList()
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_TASKS, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    String[] from = new String[]{DBHelper.COLUMN_CONTENT};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textTitle};

    MySimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    //cursor.close();
    database.close();
}
```

Если раскомментировать cursor.close(), то список не успеет заполниться и вывалится исключение. В похожих вопросах на англоязычном stackoverflow.com предлагают закрывать cursor в таких методах как onStop или onDestroy, но ведь метод onDestroy также будет вызван при смене ориентации экрана по цепочке onPasuse->onStop->onDestroy, а затем активити создастся заново onCreate->onStart->onResume. Как же быть в таком случае? И, если, все же, предложенные варианты верны, то где лучше всего объявить курсор, ведь он перестанет быть локальным.

Прошу помочь разобраться, где инициализировать объекты SQLiteDatabase и Cursor.

Или ресурсы не будут использоваться так бешено, что можно не заморачиваться и не закрывать курсор? Хотя студия настоятельно рекомендует это сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: лучше всего использовать `CursorLoader` Этот класс самостоятельно следит за жизненным циклом курсора и корректно обрабатывает повороты устройства и прочие неприятности и не требует дополнительной заботы о том, когда, где и что закрывать при работе с SQLite, беря эти обязанности на себя.